# Automatically subscribe all users based on roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but I have got the api manager working against rest services and can provision users through LDAP.

I can restrict access to certain services by role.

All good so far, however as many users will authenticate through a SPA (AngularJS) and the application will call multiple Rest Services, what I don't want users to have to do, is go to the store and subscribe to all relevant APIs, I would like the users from the LDAP server to be subscribed to all relevant services and have the roles they have limit access to the service.

Is there a way to have authentication done by just being in the identity store and authorization to be managed by the restrict by role setting.

Does this need scripting, is it a setting, or is it impossible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement isn't supported OOTB in API Manager, still you can do it with little effort.

API Manager provides REST API to subscribe APIs. You can write a client which call the REST API onbehalf of the user and subscribe him.

Have a look on [REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/#!/operations#SubscriptionindividualApi#subscriptionsPost)

Comment: Thanks Abimaram, will look at the API closer.